# How to use .filter correctly in Django and code seems not to be executed

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm trying to map positions from one table to another table, but at the moment i am really confused about using .filter.

I have a Worker class like this,

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    """Model representing a worker."""
    personal_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, help_text='Unique ID for a worker in the 

whole company')
        position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        Machine_of_Worker = models.ManyToManyField('Machine', blank=True, related_name = 'workers')
               
""" insert filtering method here """
        
        class Meta:
        ordering = ['personal_id']
    
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}'
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this book."""
        return reverse('worker-detail', args=[str(self.personal_id)])
```

a Machine class like this

```
> class Machine(models.Model):    
>         """Model representing a Machine."""
>         machine_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, help_text="enter machine number as unique id here")
>         Worker_On_Machine = models.ManyToManyField(Worker, blank=True, related_name = 'machines')
>         position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

and a position class according to this.

```
class Position(models.Model):
    """ Model representation of the positions and ground states """
    square_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, help_text='Unique ID for a position square in x/y coordinate in the whole company')
    x_pos = models.IntegerField(default = 0, help_text="enter x coordinate here")
    y_pos = models.IntegerField(default = 0, help_text="enter y coordinate here")
```

My WorkerAdmin looks like this

```
class WorkerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['worker_on_machine']
    list_display = ('position')
    fields = ['personal_id', 'Machine_of_Worker', ('position','worker_on_machine')]
```

Now I want to use a filtering method to map the `machine_id` from all accesible machines from `Machine_of_Worker` according to the position a worker is at the moment. So i tried the following in a first step, this method is located in my `class Worker`. The `actual_position` is printed correctly, when i am accessing a worker. But the rest of the code seems not to be executed. `print(machine_position)` is not displayed in the console. There are no error messages or anything else.

```
@property
def MapMachinePosition(self):
    MachineID = ''
    actual_position = self.position.square_id
    print(actual_position)
    machine_position = self.object.filter(Machine_of_Worker__position__square_id = self.position.square_id)
    print(machine_position)
    
    if machine_position.exists():
        for event in machine_position:
            if (event.position.square_id == actual_position):
                MachineID = event.position.square_id    
        
    return MachineID
worker_on_machine= MapMachinePosition
```

Maybe you can help me to find out why the code isn't executed and if the code is correct.

If you need more informations please comment.
Thanks

Comment: I found out the filtering went wrong. Correct is `machine_position = Machine.objects.filter(position__square_id = self.position.square_id)` . But i don't understand, why there wasn't an error message nor an return value in `machine_position`.